# I have uploaded to google play store an app. But it doesn't support device Huawei and other mobile phones. What could it be? This is my manifest

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

This is the AndroidManifest.xml file
I have changed everything. I delete support-screens but it didn't help. I have change permission. I have changed settings. I have changed sdk target but even that didnt help. So I dont know now what to do.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="60318" android:versionName="6.3.18" package="app.scread.com" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/CordovaWindowBackgroundTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.sharing.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/sharing_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       </manifest>
```

Comment: Probably because they don't match your compatible-screens requirements

Comment: okay. This is espcially for Huawei. I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your app should support all type of screens, if so i suggest to remove `<compatible-screens>` block from manifest file. Because there are `android:screenSize=` `large` and `xlarge` screen devices. For now your app don't support them. Check [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element)